# wait() on a group of Popen objects

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a number of Popen objects, each representing a long-running command I have started. In fact, I do not expect these commands to exit. If any of them do exit, I want to wait a few seconds and then restart. Is there a good, pythonic way to do this?

For example:

```
import random
from subprocess import Popen

procs = list()
for i in range(10):
    procs.append(Popen(["/bin/sleep", str(random.randrange(5,10))]))
```

A naive approach might be:

```
for p in procs:
    p.wait()
    print "a process has exited"
    # restart code
print "all done!"
```

But this will not alert me to the first process that has exited. So I could try

```
for p in procs:
    p.poll()
    if p.returncode is not None:
        print "a process has exited"
        procs.remove(p)
        # restart code
print "all done!"
```

However, this is a tight loop and will consume a CPU. I suppose I could add a `time.sleep(1)` in the loop so it's not busywaiting, but I lose precision.

I feel like there should be some nice way to wait on a group of pids -- am I right?

Comment: Strangely, I didn't find a graceful solution.  If you want to use the awesome `gevent`, it has a richer selection of tools, including the notion of a pool of workers you can add to at any time.  http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The "restart crashed server" task is really common, and probably shouldn't be handled by custom code unless there's a concrete reason.   See `upstart` and `systemd` and `monit`.
2. The `multiprocessing.Pool` object sounds like a win -- it automatically starts processes, and even restarts them if needed.  Unfortunately it's not very configurable.

Here's one solution with good old `Popen`:

```
import random, time
from subprocess import Popen


def work_diligently():
    cmd = ["/bin/sleep", str(random.randrange(2,4))]
    proc = Popen(cmd)
    print '\t{}\t{}'.format(proc.pid, cmd) # pylint: disable=E1101
    return proc


def spawn(num):
    return [ work_diligently() for _ in xrange(num) ]


NUM_PROCS = 3
procs = spawn(NUM_PROCS)
while True:
    print time.ctime(), 'scan'
    procs = [ 
        proc for proc in procs
        if proc.poll() is None
    ]
    num_exited = NUM_PROCS - len(procs)
    if num_exited:
        print 'Uhoh! Restarting {} procs'.format(num_exited)
        procs.extend( spawn(num_exited) )
    time.sleep(1)
```

### Output:

```
    2340    ['/bin/sleep', '2']
    2341    ['/bin/sleep', '2']
    2342    ['/bin/sleep', '3']
Mon Jun  2 18:01:42 2014 scan
Mon Jun  2 18:01:43 2014 scan
Mon Jun  2 18:01:44 2014 scan
Uhoh! Restarting 2 procs
    2343    ['/bin/sleep', '3']
    2344    ['/bin/sleep', '2']
Mon Jun  2 18:01:45 2014 scan
Uhoh! Restarting 1 procs
    2345    ['/bin/sleep', '2']
Mon Jun  2 18:01:46 2014 scan
Uhoh! Restarting 1 procs
    2346    ['/bin/sleep', '2']
Mon Jun  2 18:01:47 2014 scan
Uhoh! Restarting 2 procs
    2347    ['/bin/sleep', '3']
    2349    ['/bin/sleep', '2']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a posix operating system, you can use `os.wait` to wait for any child process. You get the process-id, which you can compare with the `pid`s of your list, to find the process, which has terminated:

```
import random
from subprocess import Popen
import os

procs = {}
for i in range(10):
    proc = Popen(["/bin/sleep", str(random.randrange(5,10))])
    procs[proc.pid] = proc

while procs:
    pid, status = os.wait()
    proc = procs.pop(pid)
    print "process %d has exited" % proc.pid
    # restart code
print "all done!"
```

Comment: Yes. This is the same behavior as posix shell `wait`.

Comment: The trouble with this behavior is the possibility of a race condition. If the process terminates before os.wait is called, it won't be waited for, and you end up having to poll every process anyway.

Comment: There is no race-condition! Every process is once returned by `os.wait` with it's `pid`.

Comment: If there are no child processes running at the time of the os.wait call, it doesn't have anything to wait on. os.wait doesn't go back in time to figure out which processes were spawned. So if the processes die before os.wait is called, it will raise an exception saying that there are no processes available to wait on.

Comment: wrong again! os.wait goes back, since there are processes, which never have been waited for. see my example.

Answer (score 0):

The [twisted process API](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/core/howto/process.html) allows efficiently responding to processes finishing and lots of other conditions.